# The events are not showing up on certain pages of my wordpress site and I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with the code

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Here is an example of what it looks like when the events are showing up [here](http://www.proudout.com/venue/?country=United%20States&city=Arlington&venue=Pinzimini&id=107163)

Then on this page, one event is meant to be showing but its not appearing for some reason you can find the link [here](http://www.proudout.com/venue/?country=United%20States&city=Arlington&venue=Arlington+Mill+Community+Center&id=224984)

I can post the whole code if needed, but I believe the issue of the problem lies in the code below

```
<div class="gpo_events">

<?php       

    foreach ( $venue_events as $post ) {
        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium');
        $url = $thumb[0];

        $country_name = tribe_get_country($post->ID);
        $city_name = tribe_get_city($post->ID);
        $venue_name = tribe_get_venue($post->ID);

        $event_url = tribe_get_event_link($post->ID);
        $params = array(
                    'country' => $country_name,
                    'city' => $city_name,
                    'venue' => $venue_name);
        $event_url_params = add_query_arg( $params, $event_url );

        ?>

        <a class="gpo_event" href="<?php echo $event_url_params; ?>">

            <?php if ( has_term( 'pride','tribe_events_cat' ) ) { ?>
                <img class="flag pride" src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/po_pride_flag.png'; ?>" alt="Pride">
            <?php } ?>

            <div class="gpo_event_cover" style="background-image:url(<?=$url?>);" ></div>

            <div class="gpo_event_facts">
                <p class="gpo_event_fact gpo_event_date">
                    <span>
                        <?php 
                            $start_date = tribe_get_start_date( $post->ID, false, 'd.m.y' );
                            $end_date = tribe_get_end_date( $post->ID, false, 'd.m.y' );

                            if ( $start_date !== $end_date ) {
                                echo $start_date ?> &ndash; <?php echo $end_date;
                            } else {
                                echo $start_date;
                            }?>
                    </span
                </p>
                <?php  $venue = tribe_get_venue($post->ID);
                    if ( !empty( $venue ) ) : ?>
                        <p class="gpo_event_fact gpo_event_venue">
                            <span>
                                <?php echo $venue; ?>
                            </span>
                        </p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <p class="gpo_event_fact gpo_event_city">
                    <span><?php  $city = tribe_get_city($post->ID);
                        if ( !empty( $city ) ) : ?><?php echo $city; ?> <?php endif; ?><?php echo(" &ndash; ")?><?php  $country = tribe_get_country($post->ID);  if ( !empty( $country ) ) : ?><?php echo $country; ?> <?php endif; ?>
                    </span>
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="gpo_event_detail">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </div>      
        </a>

        <?php if ( isMobile() &&  $events_count == 5 ) {
            $ads_shown_top = 1; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="gpo_ads_modile gpo_portrait">
            <?php include('ads/po_1_scyscraper/po_skyscraper.php'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="gpo_events">
        <?php } 
        $events_count++;
    } ?>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Edit: Had to change the links!

Comment: Why the "javascript" tag?

Comment: Sorry first time posting a question and it suggested I use that tag, but I'll remove it!